# jQuery .children error in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

I am using jQuery on my website, specifically the `children` method so I can get to lower levels of my HTML. This works fine on Chrome and Firefox, but when I use it on Internet Explorer, I get the following error:

```
error: object doesn't support property or method 'children'
```

Is this an error in IE or am I doing something wrong? Here are the lines where its pulling the error:

```
parent = $(this).parent().parent().parent();
parent.children().children().children().attr('id');
```

Is it possible that IE doesn't like it when you write `children()` that many times?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I just don't understand why IE would have a problem with this now, since I have used the `children()` method before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 1st line could be trying to reassign [the predefined global, `window.parent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.parent). While doing so may not throw an error, the global can be read-only and discard the assigned value:

```
parent = 'parent';
console.log(parent); // null or Window rather than 'parent'
```

If the snippet is within a `function`, make sure you [declare the variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470488/what-is-the-function-of-the-var-keyword-in-ecmascript-262-3rd-edition-javascript) so it's locally scoped:

```
function foo() {
    var parent = $(this)....;
    // ...
}
```

Or, use a different identifier to avoid the conflict.

```
var $parent = $(this)....;
$parent.children()...;
```

Comment: or `$parent = $(this).parents().eq(3)`